# Azure Function Logging Host vs. Function

Tags: azure-functions, ilogger

I have the standard DI logging setup in a multiproject solution but in the Function logging, only the ILogger instance from the params is shown, not the ILogger<T> logs from the services called from the Function. The ILogger<T> logs do however show in the Host logs. Can you get the ILogger<T> logs from the services to show in the Function log?

`TestFunction.cs`

```cs
private readonly ILogger<TestFunction> _logger;
private readonly ITestService _testService;

public TestFunction(ILogger<TestFunction> logger, ITestService testService)
{
   _logger = logger;
   _testService = testService;
}

[FunctionName("TestFunction")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
   log.LogInformation("I am from the log,");
   _logger.LogInformation("I am from the _logger");

   await _testService.TestLogs();

   log.LogInformation("Ending from the log,");
   _logger.LogInformation("Ending from the _logger");

   return new OkObjectResult("Fin");
}
```

`TestService.cs`

```cs
public interface IMessageQueueService
{ 
    Task TestLogs();
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{

   private readonly ILogger<TestService> _logger;

   public TestService(ILogger<TestService> logger) 
   {
       _logger = logger;
   }
 
   public async Task TestLogs()
   {
      _logger.LogInformation("I am _logger in a service");
   }
}
```

The Function log shows this:

```
2022-11-30T15:17:07.988 [Information] Executing 'TestFunction' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=cc28beea-f9ec-4642-9946-cf5a588df320)
2022-11-30T15:17:07.988 [Information] I am from the log,
2022-11-30T15:17:07.989 [Information] Ending from the log,
2022-11-30T15:17:07.996 [Information] Executed 'TestFunction' (Succeeded, Id=cc28beea-f9ec-4642-9946-cf5a588df320, Duration=17ms)
```

The Host log shows this:

```
2022-11-30T15:46:41.713 [Information] Executing 'TestFunction' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=5f571267-3edb-4c99-8d15-5c7dee5e6446)
2022-11-30T15:46:41.714 [Information] I am from the log,
2022-11-30T15:46:41.714 [Information] I am from the _logger
2022-11-30T15:46:41.714 [Information] I am _logger in a service
2022-11-30T15:46:41.714 [Information] Ending from the log,
2022-11-30T15:46:41.714 [Information] Ending from the _logger
2022-11-30T15:46:41.714 [Information] Executed 'TestFunction' (Succeeded, Id=5f571267-3edb-4c99-8d15-5c7dee5e6446, Duration=8ms)
```

How can I get all of it to show in the Function log?

Comment: Is this an Isolated function?

Answer (score 0):

- Well once you specify log level in the `` file you will be able to log in function host also.
- to setup log level you will have specify the namespace and log level i.e. Information, warning etc., in the in  `host.json`.

My `host.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "FunctionApp17": "Information"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here my namespace is `FunctionApp17`

My function trigger :

```
namespace FunctionApp17
{
    public  class Function1
    {
        private readonly ITestServices testServices;
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> loggingThroughDependencyInjection;

        public Function1(ITestServices testServices,ILogger<Function1>loggingThroughDependencyInjection)
        {
            this.testServices = testServices;
            this.loggingThroughDependencyInjection = loggingThroughDependencyInjection;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public  async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger loggingThroughPassedParameter)
        {
            loggingThroughPassedParameter.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            loggingThroughDependencyInjection.LogInformation("Logging using Dependency Injection ");
            testServices.test();

            return new OkObjectResult("Triggered the http function");
        }
    }
}
```

TestService :

```
namespace FunctionApp17
{
    public interface ITestServices
    {
        void test();
    }

    public class TestServices : ITestServices
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TestServices> loggingThroughDependencyInjection;

        public TestServices(ILogger<TestServices> loggingThroughDependencyInjection)
        {
            this.loggingThroughDependencyInjection = loggingThroughDependencyInjection;
        }
        public void test()
        {
            loggingThroughDependencyInjection.LogInformation("Logging using Depency Injection in TestService class");
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp17.Startups))]
namespace FunctionApp17
{
    public class Startups : FunctionsStartup

    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ITestServices,TestServices>();
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

[image]